# Validations on tableless form fields in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, custom-validators

I am attempting to run a form destined for the app's home page, which uses simultaneously tableless and database-stored variables.  I need to run validations on the form.  I need to run validations, one in particular which compares two of the tableless values.

My eventual goal is to get the validations running client-side via the following gem:
https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations
Initially though, I want to get the validations working upon form submission.

A first question that arises is which model should hold the mail validation logic.  The homePage has to do many things, is not a model and, above all, the search results lead to a different controller.

Subsequently, although some validations are one-off and don't really need to be factored out, I would place the validation logic in app/validators/different_objects_validator.rb

```
class DifferentObjectsValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def different_objects
    errors.add(:different_objects, "cannot be less than quantity") unless
     self.quantity >= self.different_objects
  end

end
```

Form data is:

```
<%= form_tag result_quote_request_path, :method => :get do %>
      Base    <%= number_field :quote, :base, :size => 5 %>
      Height    <%= number_field :quote, :height, :size => 5 %>
      Quantity    <%= number_field :quote, :quantity, :size => 5, :value => 1 %>
      Different source objects   <%= number_field :quote, :different_objects, :size => 5, :value => 1 %>
    <%= submit_tag "find", :name => nil %>
<% end -%>
```

Then

```
class Quote  < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates :different_objects, different_objects_valid => true
```

After restarting Thin web server, this results in:

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):

But this is a bit of a red herring: without the validation, the form generates a search result

I realize many things may be wrong here.  I am having trouble getting the proper focus of where the validations are invoked combined with tableless states.

Comment: whay have u given `:name => nil` in form submit?

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from the following:

```
<%= submit_tag "find", :name => nil %>
```

Simply do

```
<%= submit_tag "find" %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. It is not the source of the error; the undefined method is called upon the target path. Without the validation, the form generates a search result.  Removing the offending proposition, with the validation, still leads to the same error.